# What exception to throw when a property setter is not allowed?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, properties

I have a base class that has a virtual property:

```
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

then I have a derived class that overrides only the getter of the property

```
public override string Name
{
    get { return "Fixed Name"; }
}
```

The problem is this only overrides the getter. If someone calls the setter the base class setter will get called, and the caller won't know that it's ineffective.

So I thought I'd do something like:

```
public override string Name
{
    get { return "Fixed Name"; }
    set { throw new Exception(); } //which exception type?
}
```

So two (related questions):

1. Is there a better pattern for me to use?
2. If I should be using the above pattern, what exception to use?

**Edit**: Some reasons why one exception would be preferred over another would be good. My co-worker and I have had the same argument between `NotSupported` and `InvalidOperation`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need the setter in the base class?

Comment: @DarylTeo yes, the base class needs to support setting the name manually, although it could be in the constructor.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Throw [NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) exception.
Quote from the link:

> There are methods that are not supported in the base class, with the
>   expectation that these methods will be implemented in the derived
>   classes instead. The derived class might implement only a subset of
>   the methods from the base class, and throw NotSupportedException for
>   the unsupported methods.

My opinion is that [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) is not a correct option.
Quote from MSDN:

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

There is nothing about current state in your situation. It is that the class contract does not support the operation.

Comment: hm.. that quote makes sense, although it's kind of the opposite of what I'm doing.

Comment: +1 The quote is the exact answer to the question and is how I am doing it when I have derived classes which cannot for some reason implemented an abstract method

Comment: @Ray - You are doing exactly the same. Read it again:)

Comment: @Petar: Agreed - deleting my answer. I was looking for UnsupportedOperationException, which is the appropriate one in Java, and after failing to find it went for InvalidOperationException which is wrong for the reasons you've given.

Answer (score 9):

It breaks Liskov Substitution Principle and that's why it is bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

If you can you could try to move setter to constructor of the base class and make setter private. Or as Jon suggested create abstract base class / interface with getters that are supported in all implementations.

This would avoid the whole situation with throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

If the base class actually allows setting the name (as opposed to exposing an abstract setter which isn't guaranteed to work), derived classes should do so as well.  If you want a hierarchy which includes some classes where the name can be set and some where it cannot, both kinds of class should inherit from an abstract `ReadableXX` class with a non-virtual read-write `Name` property that chains to abstract `GetName` and `SetName` methods.  It should also provide some means of indicating whether `SetName` will be supported (e.g. a `CanSetName` method).  A read-only variant of the class could define a "new" read-only `Name` property that would chain to `GetName`, and have its `SetName` override throw `NotSupportedException`.  If the specification for the class says that `SetName` will only work if `CanSetName` returns true, then having `SetName` throw an exception in classes where `CanSetName` returns false would not violate the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Answer (score -3):

Here I'd go for a [NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx).

Comment: -1 This signals that it isn't **yet** implemented, but is going to. Most of the times, this isn't suitable in production

Comment: Fair point. Often used as a default exception for code generators.